# Encrypt and decrypt a license key in PHP

Tags: php, license-key

I need to generate a license key with a given name, product title and an expiry date. If one of my customers buys my product and uses it, he has to enter this license key.

I tried so much methods and I have no clue how to achieve this in PHP. The key should be safe for reproduction. What would be the best way to create a license key encryption and decryption in PHP?

Comment: There are no solutions to encrypt and decrypt data in PHP? [Where did you look?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.crypto.php)

Comment: Generate licence key use `md5` or `sha1` and store them in your database when it is requested compare it with the stored value give the desired results

Comment: This old fashioned way to 'grant access' to a software installation by means of a license key to be accepted is probably the best way to scare people away from using your product. Rethink. Experience shows: the thread that your business will be ruined because people use your 'product' without paying for it simply is not true. Be open instead. It works and looks _much_ better.

Comment: If i use md5 or sha1 method some one easily decrypt through decryption online convertor and they can identify my license key format.Is there any algorithm ?

Comment: This type of "enter a key to unlock" protection does nothing to stop sharing of the key, particularly without a phone-home to check for the license used with multiple IP and perhaps also MAC addresses. Domain based locking is more standard for a web product, and most effective with a Loader based solution because the domain can be captured for testing before a PHP script has a chance to modify $_SERVER. A home brew domain test in PHP will likely be easily defeated with a prepend script to set the domain the license code is looking for. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code may help you:

```
function encrypt($sData, $secretKey){
    $sResult = '';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($sData);$i++){
        $sChar    = substr($sData, $i, 1);
        $sKeyChar = substr($secretKey, ($i % strlen($secretKey)) - 1, 1);
        $sChar    = chr(ord($sChar) + ord($sKeyChar));
        $sResult .= $sChar;

    }
    return encode_base64($sResult);
} 

function decrypt($sData, $secretKey){
    $sResult = '';
    $sData   = decode_base64($sData);
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($sData);$i++){
        $sChar    = substr($sData, $i, 1);
        $sKeyChar = substr($secretKey, ($i % strlen($secretKey)) - 1, 1);
        $sChar    = chr(ord($sChar) - ord($sKeyChar));
        $sResult .= $sChar;
    }
    return $sResult;
}

function encode_base64($sData){
    $sBase64 = base64_encode($sData);
    return str_replace('=', '', strtr($sBase64, '+/', '-_'));
}

function decode_base64($sData){
    $sBase64 = strtr($sData, '-_', '+/');
    return base64_decode($sBase64.'==');
}
```

Here

```
$secretKey; // Your secret key can be anything which you only know it. So no one easily decrypt through any tool. (recommended often change the $secretKey).
```

Comment: thanks.I tried your encryption method with the $value='test'.Its working great but encryption data would be "f‘Í´>ÑE6ë‰5»5ÚR?˜×ŽvûîmÃB½ªVÇV".can't we make it as an alpha numeric characters or like ABCD-HIJK-HGTY ?

Comment: I have changed the script. Have a look.

Comment: I have tested this like $test = 'test20130221';$before = encrypt($test, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN');//prints  wqa1t3Z1d3p4e3x8    $after = decrypt ($before, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN');//prints  ��-�Mw�m�  .Is it a correct way to test this ?

Comment: Test like below: (its working)
`echo $a = encrypt("test20130221","ABCDEFGHIJKLMN");
echo $b = decrypt("wqa1t3Z1d3p4e3x8","ABCDEFGHIJKLMN");`

Comment: thanks for your help.I'm having joomla site.The decryption method returning me ��-�Mw�m�.

Comment: Its working for me.I just added unnecessary line in between the coding.Thank you so much Prabu..

Answer (score 0):

well there is [NuCoder](http://www.nusphere.com/products/nucoder.htm) which can provide such type of functionality

Comment: I just want to do in my package.Any other way ?

Comment: Does it require a loader? Is it currently maintained?

Answer (score -1):

try `next service www.e-ll.ro | Encrypt with License Key Any PHP Code/Source/Script/Website`

Answer (score -1):

For local license go for ionCube or php's openssl as mcrypt is abandonned. For remote license go for php's curl. It probably gives you some idea how to do so http://www.phplicengine.com I also suggest to take a look at phpseclib in github or packagist. It uses first openssl, if not available then switches to mcrypt. With openssl or mcrypt you can encrypt and decrypt. As about method I suggest AES_128.